# Nested class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, nested-class

I'm following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868) tutorial, but after completing step 6, I'm left with an error: "MyGestureDetector cannot be resolved to a type" when I try to instantiate a "new MyGestureDetector()".

Code:

```
package com.example.rotatingdialer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static Bitmap imageOriginal, imageScaled;
    private static Matrix matrix;

    private ImageView dialer;
    private int dialerHeight, dialerWidth;
    private GestureDetector detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // load the image only once
        if (imageOriginal == null) {
            imageOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        // initialize the matrix only once
        if (matrix == null) {
            matrix = new Matrix();
        } else {
            // not needed, you can also post the matrix immediately to restore the old state
            matrix.reset();
        }

        detector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());

        dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_ring);
        dialer.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
        dialer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // method called more than once, but the values only need to be initialized one time
                if (dialerHeight == 0 || dialerWidth == 0) {
                    dialerHeight = dialer.getHeight();
                    dialerWidth = dialer.getWidth();

                    // resize
                    Matrix resize = new Matrix();
                    resize.postScale((float)Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getWidth(), (float)Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getHeight());
                    imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);

                    // translate to the image view's center
                    float translateX = dialerWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;
                    float translateY = dialerHeight / 2 - imageScaled.getHeight() / 2;
                    matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);

                    dialer.setImageBitmap(imageScaled);
                    dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Simple implementation of an {@link OnTouchListener} for registering the dialer's touch events. 
     */
    private class MyOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        private double startAngle;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
                    startAngle = currentAngle;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
            }
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Simple implementation of a {@link SimpleOnGestureListener} for detecting a fling event. 
         */
        private class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                dialer.post(new FlingRunnable(velocityX + velocityY));
                return true;
            }
        }

        /**
         * A {@link Runnable} for animating the the dialer's fling.
         */
        private class FlingRunnable implements Runnable {

            private float velocity;

            public FlingRunnable(float velocity) {
                this.velocity = velocity;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Math.abs(velocity) > 5) {
                    rotateDialer(velocity / 75);
                    velocity /= 1.0666F;

                    // post this instance again
                    dialer.post(this);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return The angle of the unit circle with the image view's center
         */
        private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
            double x = xTouch - (dialerWidth / 2d);
            double y = dialerHeight - yTouch - (dialerHeight / 2d);

            switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
                case 1:
                    return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
                case 2:
                    return 180 - Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
                case 3:
                    return 180 + (-1 * Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);
                case 4:
                    return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return The selected quadrant.
         */
        private int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
            if (x >= 0) {
                return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
            } else {
                return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Rotate the dialer.
         * 
         * @param degrees The degrees, the dialer should get rotated.
         */
        private void rotateDialer(float degrees) {
            matrix.postRotate(degrees, dialerWidth/2, dialerHeight/2);
            dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
//            dialer.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(imageScaled, 0, 0, imageScaled.getWidth(), imageScaled.getHeight(), matrix, true));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

...did I go wrong somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this (that is, without refactoring the class structure of these 4 classes (Activity, touch listener, gesture detector, fling runnable)) is to call it as follows. You'll have to move your `MyTouchListener` instantiation out into a separate declaration, and then you can use that to create a new instance of the `MyGestureDetector` class:

```
    MyOnTouchListener onTouchListener = new MyOnTouchListener();
    detector = new GestureDetector(this, onTouchListener.new MyGestureDetector());

    dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_ring);
    dialer.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
```

Comment: So simple...yet so genius... Thanks a bunch! :)